# Heap buffer overflow error, Leetcode problem 941, Valid Mountain Array, using C

Tags: memory-leaks

I am currently learning c and trying to do some problems on leetcode to better myself.
The problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-mountain-array/
I am getting an error as such, [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b46AA.png) apperently a read error.
However whenever i run my code on my pc i don't get any errors, even using valgrind.
Here is my code:

```
bool validMountainArray(int* arr, int arrSize)
{   
    bool is_m_array = false;
    bool peek = false; 
     int peek_point = 0;
    int end_of_slope = 0;
    int k = 0;
    if( arrSize >= 3)
    {
        while (arr[k] < arr[k+1] && arr[k] < arrSize)
        {
            k++;
        }
        peek = true;
        peek_point = k;
    }
    if (peek == true)
    {
        while(arr[peek_point] > arr[peek_point+1] && arr[peek_point] < arrSize)
    {
        peek_point++;
        end_of_slope = peek_point+1;
        printf("end Of SLOPE %d, arrSize %d \n", end_of_slope, arrSize);
    }
    }
    if (peek == true && end_of_slope == arrSize)
    {
        is_m_array = true;
    }
    return is_m_array;
}
```

I have tried several different inputs and they all seem to work just fine!
For example:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   int arr[9]= {1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1};
    if (validMountainArray(arr, 9) == true)
    {
        printf("True");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("False");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Will return True.

Anyone got any ide what i am missing here?

Comment: `while (arr[k] < arr[k+1] && arr[k] < arrSize)` ==> `while (arr[k] < arr[k+1] && k < arrSize)` but even then you access `arr[arrSize]` which does not exist.

Comment: If you have an array with four elements `{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }` how many times will your first `while` loop (inside the `if`) run... and what are the `5` (!!) elements you read from?

Comment: `arr[k + 1]` when `k == arrSize - 1`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. im not quiet sure i understand what you mean with the second comment. I am stepping untill i hit an integer arr[i+1] that is not greater then arr[i] whenever i hit that condition i set the peek to that, and from there on every value however many there is i suppose to be less then the pervious one. if i reach the arrSize, and my current index for arr is equal to arrsize i can conclude that the conditions are met!

Comment: Just try it with pen and paper, line by line ... or with a debugger :-)

Comment: If you want to see [my attempt](https://pastecode.io/s/w45296uk) (expires in 6 hours), password is "I don't want to try on my own"

Comment: Found a  bug in my attempt (lol)... second if should be `if ((k == 1) || (k == n)) return 0;`